# How to use Exist sql function in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

```
var _query = _dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
             .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date >= From.Date && x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && (x.Type == Common.TransactionType.CPV || x.Type == Common.TransactionType.BPV) && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode && x.DebitAmount > 0)
             .GroupBy(v => new { v.AccountCode})
             .Select(g => new
              {
                 AccountCode = g.Key.AccountCode,
              });

var balances = _dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
               .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode)
             //.Exist(_query.Account) (I want only account which exist in upper query)
               .GroupBy(v => new { v.AccountCode})
               .Select(g => new
               {
                   AccountCode = g.Key.AccountCode,
                   Balance = g.Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount),
                });
```

I want to use something like EXIST here in first query I have some specific accounts and in 2nd query I want to calculate balances of those accounts.
Can you please tell how I can use Exist function in LINQ.
Thank you.

I want this query to be implemented in LINQ:

```
SELECT `c`.`AccountCode`, `c`.`CompanyCode` AS `LocationCode`, COALESCE(SUM(`c`.`DebitAmount` - `c`.`CreditAmount`), 0) AS `Balance`
    FROM `CashVoucherDetails` AS `c`
    WHERE (CONVERT(`c`.`CreationDate`, date) <= '2022-12-20') AND (`c`.`CompanyCode` = '002') and `c`.`AccountCode` IN 
    (
        SELECT `c`.`AccountCode`
        FROM `CashVoucherDetails` AS `c`
        WHERE ((((CONVERT(`c`.`CreationDate`, date) >= '2022-12-20') AND (CONVERT(`c`.`CreationDate`, date) <= '2022-12-20')) AND `c`.`Type`     IN ('CPV', 'BPV')) AND (`c`.`CompanyCode` = '002')) AND (`c`.`DebitAmount` > 0)
        GROUP BY `c`.`AccountCode` 
    )
    GROUP BY `c`.`AccountCode`, `c`.`CompanyCode`;
```

Comment: So first query will get some accounts and in the second query, you only want to filter data from first query. If combine them to one query is what you want?

Comment: Exactly. I want this.

Comment: I think you just combine your two ```where``` conditions then you will get what you want. right?

Comment: But In first query Date Range is different and In 2nd query date range is different,

Comment: That's not a problem. In first one for example you get the data from 12/01 to 12/10 and in the second one you got the data which date is less than 12/10. What you want is the data between 12/01 to 12/10 and in second the date filter is not important because that condition is include in the first one

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Contains` or `Any`.

```cs
_dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
    .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode)
    .Where(x => _query.Select(q => q.AccountCode).Contains(x.AccountCode))
```

Or

```cs
.Where(x => _query.Any(q => q.AccountCode == x.AccountCode))
```

Comment: I got error while using this statement. Error
Unknown column 'c1.AccountCode' in 'field list'

Comment: @ÅfsħąlÃtħąr try the second code with `Any`

Comment: I've tried both statements.

Comment: @ÅfsħąlÃtħąr so on which column do you want to check the Exists? you just need to use the same column. I have written my answer as per your code only

Comment: I want to check on AccountCode which you already did.

Comment: @ÅfsħąlÃtħąr was it working before introducing my changes?

Comment: Yes, it was working.

Comment: When I added ToList with first query. Its working but I dont want to list here.
Here is image link: https://ibb.co/VVZXMLr

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that

```
var balances = _dbContext.CashVoucherDetails
           .Where(x => x.CreationDate.Date <= To.Date && x.CompanyCode == BranchCode && _query.Any(q => q.AccountCode == x.AccountCode))
           .GroupBy(v => new { v.AccountCode})
           .Select(g => new
           {
               AccountCode = g.Key.AccountCode,
               Balance = g.Sum(x => x.DebitAmount - x.CreditAmount),
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got error when I use _query.any.
Error Unknown column 'c1.AccountCode' in 'field list'

Comment: Strange it should work correctly. Check the column names.

Comment: I double check it but column name is same.